# Transferring attributes based on location in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am using QGIS and I have a shapefile (shp1) mapping all private properties in a region, and another one, with the states boundaries.

The attributes tables have no field in common.

What I would like to do is to add a field on shp1 regarding the state that polygon is located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what attributes you have in your states you can join them based on location using QGIS. The tool can be found at "Vector"-"Data Management"-"Join attributes based on location". Your target will be your shp1. It then should bring you all attributes from your states.